# Double frontend cookies causing intermittent login issues

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, login, cookie

The site runs Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Customers have been reporting issues with logging in. I've been able to replicate this myself on Safari only (do not know the exact steps to replicate yet though).

Somehow, 2 frontend cookies generated (this is not the issue):

```
frontend    fs66qk6lbfjriuf873mrbdk199  .www.foobar.com /   8 March 2014 4:34:40 pm AEDT    34 B    
frontend    fs66qk6lbfjriuf873mrbdk199  www.foobar.com  /   8 March 2014 4:34:40 pm AEDT    34 B
```

The above is no issue, and you can still login on the frontend with the above cookies. However, sometimes the cookies look like:

```
frontend    deleted .www.foobar.com /   8 March 2014 4:34:40 pm AEDT    34 B    
frontend    fs66qk6lbfjriuf873mrbdk199  www.foobar.com  /   8 March 2014 4:34:40 pm AEDT    34 B
```

The above definitely causes issues and I am not able to login.

Under System >> Config >> Web:

```
Cookie Lifetime: 86400
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: (blank)
Use HTTP Only: No
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Should I be setting a Cookie Domain? The symptom that the customer sees is just being redirected to the login page with no errors.

Comment: See also [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22363/erratic-cookie-related-login-problem) for a potentially excellent solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing the old cookies and setting the `Cookie Domain` as `www.foobar.com` has helped out solve the issue.

Comment: I am facing the same situation , but your solution doesn;t work for me . did u tried smth else ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks - setting cookie domain as www.mydomain.com solved my problem of customer login in safari.

go to - system >> configuration >> general >> web >> session cookie management.

also i changed cookie lifetime to 33600, i do not know if that helped too.