# Cookies not working with subdomains

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, cookie

We have a main site at **`example.com`**. Logging into **`example.com/admin`** works fine there.

But on a testing site at **`test.example.com/admin`** I cannot log into the admin without first deleting all **`example.com`** cookies. Then I can log in, but as soon as I log into **`example.com/admin`** my next click on the test server kicks me back to the login page.

I don't know if this affects customer logins.

Is there some configuration in the main site or testing site that would solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anna makes some good points and her answer will work for a lot of people, but not for me, so I'm posting my own answer. Perhaps my problem was much more fundamental than the one she addresses.

My solution was to change my site's domain from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. In fact, my research on the internet suggests that the reason sites like Amazon, Google, Ebay, and every other major web destination use the `www` prefix may be in large part due to the way cookies work. Maybe not.

The default way that a cookie works is that it applies to all subdomains. So if `example.com` sends you a cookie, then you visit `mail.example.com`, `smile.example.com`, or `devsite.example.com`, then your browser will send that cookie to those sites and those sites will try to use the cookie. But they won't be able to find your session unless they all use a common session folder. And even then, you'd likely have problems because of different database configurations, different application structures, etc.

Making the change involved creating `301` redirects in my root htaccess file, changing the secure/insecure urls in the magento `core_config_data` database table, changing the site's `ServerName` in Apache `VirtualHosts`, and updating DNS / nameserver settings. But it was well worth it.

By making my main site `www.example.com`, its cookies now would only apply to subdomains thereof, such as `mail.www.example.com` (and we don't have any such subdomains). Client browsers that get the `www.example.com` cookie do not send it to `devsite.example.com`, and the issue is solved. Plus it's really nice to have a `www` in front of our domain name.

Comment: I wish I could give multiple Up Votes for this answer. I am looking for a solution for months and everyone keeps saying about Cookie Path and Cookie Domain, but that will not fix the problem if you don't use www. Thank you!!

Comment: We already have www in the cookie domain, but it does still fail...

Comment: What does still fail?

Answer (score 13):

1. On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration. Then in the panel on the left, under General, click Web.
2. Expand the Session Cookie Management section

In the `example.com` shop, set the following:

3. Set the Cookie Domain to example.com (usually this setting would be .example.com with a dot in front, you might try it without in this case).

In the `test.example.com` shop, set the following:

4. Set the Cookie domain to .test.example.com on the test-environment. (the "." in front of the domain should be fine here)

Comment: Just a note, Step 3 about the `.` in front of the domain, is important!

Comment: Hi Anna. Should the cookie domain be set to ".example.com" in the `example.com` admin, the `test.example.com` admin, or both?

Comment: I'd set it as default config (which is your example.com admin I guess). So this means .example.com for all scopes.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I'm not sure here. You understand I have two completely separate magento installations on two different machines, right? One uses `example.com`, the other `test.example.com`. They both have *their own* admins. But you are only telling me to set a domain for one of the admins. Are you saying I should leave the other blank?

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed I was not aware these are 2 sepereate installations. Does the main shop run with or without www-Domain?
You could set the Cookie Domain on the Test to `test.example.com` and on the main shop to `www.example.com` then to avoid cookie overlapping.

Comment: The main domain is `example.com` and I believe we have `www.example.com` redirect to `example.com`. Is there no way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Previously, we had testing sites at ugly urls like `http;//123.45.67.89/~systemuser/` (where the admin site would be `http;//123.45.67.89/~systemuser/admin` ). For the sake of the non-tech-savvy management, I wanted to start using nicer urls, like `june2015.example.com`. If that is impossible, then I'll perhaps use a different domain like `example2.com` which we have available.

Comment: I found this question/answer;: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/whats-the-correct-cookie-config-for-a-magento-site-split-across-multiple-instan?rq=1
It seems like they found a solution, but again I am not sure exactly how they implemented it.

Comment: So, Anna, I guess the answer to this question is beyond your reach?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. The answer you found looks really similar. I'll update my answer with my suggested solution.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I don't think playing with the initial dot will solve the problem. See the PHP manual here for function `setcookie` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), under "domain":"Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains." I'm looking at file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php` method `renewSession()`. It is supposed to delete cookies of parent domains! Perhaps this is bug?

Comment: comment from the year 2018: leading dots are assumed in modern browsers per RFC 6265 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884869/1004697

Comment: I changed my domain to `.test.company.de`, now I can't login to the backend anymore. There is no error showing, it just reloads the login form.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change adminhtml cookie name for subdomains.

Two changes in file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`.

In function `preDispatch` change lines

```
/** @var $session Mage_Core_Model_Session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $this->_sessionNamespace))->start();
```

to

```
$namespace = $this->_sessionNamespace.($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='subdomain.example.com'?'_subdomain':'');
/** @var $session Mage_Core_Model_Session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $namespace))->start();
```

In function `setRedirectWithCookieCheck` change

```
/** @var $session Mage_Core_Model_Session */
session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $this->_sessionNamespace));
```

to

```
$namespace = $this->_sessionNamespace.($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='subdomain.example.com'?'_subdomain':'');
/** @var $session Mage_Core_Model_Session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $namespace));
```

And after that search for text

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
```

in all files and replace it with

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'.($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='subdomain.example.com'?'_subdomain':'')));
```

if any occurances would be found.

Comment: Can you explain in words how your code alters client and server cookie interactions to isolate sessions?

Comment: @ButtleButkus the problem is that example.com/admin sets cookie with name `adminhtml` for the domain `.example.com`.

When you try to authorize at test.example.com/admin, it tries to do something with the cookie `adminhtml` for `.test.example.com`.

The problems differ on Magento settings. The main problem is that you cannot modify cookie of the main domain from subdomain.

The code above makes Magento to create cookie `adminhtml` for example.com and cookie `adminhtml_subdomain` for subdomain.example.com, so they will not mix in any way.

Change `subdomain` to the correct one you use.

Comment: That's good for admin side. But frontend side also should change cookie name in this kind of solution, right?

Comment: @ButtleButkus you are right. Sorry, I did not write this because I did not have such kind of problem.

Comment: It's ok, still useful for some people probably.

Comment: @ButtleButkus of course you can expand the receipe for the whole site. I have changed the answer above. Now authorization works for frontend too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not able to login to your frontend (customer session cannot be created) because of the cookies issues, then please override the respective core file

> Pre 1.8.x. versions - app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/session.php

and

> from 1.8.x. version app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php

Comment out the lines pointed out in this thread. This has fixed the issue with customer login on the frontend on pre 1.8.x version store.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34057/695