# Can't login to staging servers without deleting cookies first. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1, login, cookie

We have multiple clones of our main shop at www.mainsite.com for testing and developing.

e.g. test.mainsite.com, fbk.test.mainsite.com and isk.test.mainsite.com,

There is a big issues with the cookies...

Users can't work in all test sites at the same time (Frontend and Backend). They first have to delete all other cookies from the other domains before they can login.

The cookie domain is matching the domain name on every domain, on mainsite.com the cookie domain is `mainsite.com` on test.mainsite.com the cookie domain is `test.mainsite.com` and so on...

The cookie path is set to `/` everywhere

Comment: This seems to just be an issue with magento 1. Im going to see if I can find the github issue for you

Comment: Are your cookie domains overridden on any other config scope?

Comment: No, they are not

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71283/cookies-not-working-with-subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the bug is a wildcard selector in the cookie domain which is set for unknown reasons, e.g. `.test.mainsite.com`

So if you are logged in into `test.mainsite.com`, then a cookie with cookie domain `.test.mainsite.com` is set. If you now try to login to `fbk.test.mainsite.com` then it does not work, because a cookie with cookie domain `.fbk.test.mainsite.com` is getting set, but there is already a cookie with the cookie domain `.test.mainsite.com` which also matches fbk.test.mainsite.com because of the dot at the start which is a wildcard selector.

We solved it by changing the cookie domain of the main site from `mainsite.com` to `www.mainsite.com` and changing the subdomain names to this:

```
fbk.test.mainsite.com -> fbk-test.mainsite.com
isk.test.mainsite.com -> isk-test.mainsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to delete cookies. You can use Chrome incognito mode or firefox private browsing.

Doesn't solve the issue but certainly makes working with it easier.

Comment: Thats not a good solution for the problem, it is only a workaround.