# Shopping carts appearing empty or showing unexpected items

Tags: magento-1.9, session, shopping-cart, customer-session

I've had a few customers saying that when they try adding items to the cart, the cart then goes empty or shows other items in the cart that they haven't added and I wondered if anyone else has had such issues (using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1)?

I believe that it may be their previous abandoned cart items that are being re-added to the cart - i'm certainly hoping it's that and not another customer's cart items being added. I also noticed that some customer's appear to have 3 or 4 abandoned carts within the same hour or two, according to the abandoned carts report.

This is the problem as described by the customer:

1. Login
2. Add an item to the cart and then I'm logged out again
3. Login again but the shopping cart is either empty or contains items that I haven't ordered
4. Logout
5. Login again but the shopping cart is either empty or contains items that I haven't ordered

I suspect that this is somehow a session issue. We're saving sessions to the DB and these are the settings that I have;

```
Cookie Lifetime: 86400
Use HTTP Only: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
Validate REMOTE_ADDR: No
Validate HTTP_VIA: No
Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: No
Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT: No
Use SID on Frontend: No
```

The site is also just using http with the usual switch to https for the cart and checkout.

Comment: Deactivate cache and see if problem persists. If not, fix cache. Or exclude cart from cache.

Comment: Cache issue? Maybe some kind of full page cache is installed? Varnish? And how many rows do you have in `core_session` table?

Comment: @Neklo.com There are over 14000 rows in the core_session table. We also use Mirasvit FPC.

Comment: Looks like this can be addressed to Mirasvit support. And what kind of cache storage is used? Files, memcache, redis?

Comment: @Neklo.com Mirasvit confirmed that their module doesn't cache any part of the cart or checkout, so that rules cache out. They also said that the issue may be connected to double frontend cookies and advised to set Cookie Path: / and Cookie Domain:  www.domain.tld accordingly as: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/double-frontend-cookies-causing-intermittent-login-issues

Comment: And did it help in your case?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with my Magento site. I tried clearing my cookies, it didn't work. I cleared the cache, it didn't work. I cleared the sessions in the DB, it didn't work. I changed the sessions to file session, it didn't work.

I found out that my server's disk storage was full, delete some large files, and it solve the issue.